# Problem saving data with cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm having a strange problem saving data with cakePHP. I'll explain as I go.

This is the controller header just in case its useful:

```
var $helpers = array('Html','Form','Js','Ajax');
    var $components = array('RequestHandler');
    var $name = 'Parts';
    var $paginate = array(
                        'limit'=>25,
                        'order'=>array('Part.customer'=>'asc')
                        );
```

This is my controller code for saving the form data:

```
//list items for table
    $parts = $this->Paginate('Part');
    $this->set('parts',$parts); ]

//save data
if(!empty($this->data)){    
        if ($this->Part->save($this->data)) {
           $this->Session->setFlash('Part added to database.','default',array('class'=>'flash-success'));            
           $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));        
        }else{
           $this->Session->setFlash('Failed to add part to database, please try again.','default',array('class'=>'flash-failure'));            
           $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));        
        }
    }
```

This is my form in the view:

```
        echo $this->Form->create('Part');
        echo $this->Form->input('customer');
        echo $this->Form->input('part_number');
        echo $this->Form->input('foil');
        echo $this->Form->input('base');
        echo $this->Form->input('base_color');
        echo $this->Form->input('description',array('cols'=>21));
        echo $this->Form->input('moulding');
        echo $this->Form->input('foil_diameter');
        echo $this->Form->input('tool');
        echo $this->Form->input('impressions');
        echo $this->Form->input('spray_jig');
        echo $this->Form->input('prep');
        echo $this->Form->input('pack');
        echo $this->Form->end('Add Part');
```

Now, if I enter information into the form upto and including spray_jig the from will save and the data will be saved. If I fill the form before spray_jig the form will not submit. I haven't got any data validation going on yet and the fields are a mixture of VARCHAR's INT's and one TEXT.

This has me baffled, can you suggest the problem *and/or* a good way to troubleshoot?

**Note:** spray_jig is standard int(11) field.

Comment: does the database allow nulls on spray_jig?

Comment: your sure you have field in the databse named spray_jig right?

Comment: I have checked the spelling of all fields, they are ok. All fields have NULL set to no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution - it appears **INT** fields cannot have null values. Once all INT fields where entered, the form submits.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to change the application to debug mode and look at the sql it is running, and copy the sql and try to run it in your database.